# How to use less with php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles, less

i'm using wordpress and i would like to be able to change all the same color of my website by changing one php function on my admin panel.
I tried to do that on my custom-style.php but it don't work :

```
@main_color: <?php the_field('main_color', 'option'); ?>;
a{
color: @main_color;
}
```

I also tried this way on my header.php :

```
<style type="text/css">
@main_color: <?php the_field('main_color', 'option'); ?>;
</style>
```

Comment: 1. where is the connection to `less`? and 2. certainly css rules do work in general. I suggest you post the example of the html code you want to style, then we can see what rules you need.

Comment: Ok, I just see that some funny guy had the idea to name a style sheet language just like one of the oldest utilities in the gnu world. What a great idea.

Comment: is this [<?php the_field('main_color', 'option'); ?>] returning data or blank?

Comment: Less is working and the php field too. When I put a color like #fff instead of the php field it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser doesn't recognize less. You have to compile less or use normal css.

Answer (score 0):

check below link i hope help you
[lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)

when you use external lib you must change file ext to .less.php good luck

Comment: I changed file name to custom-style.less.php and i put this on <head> : <?php include ('inc/lessc.inc.php') ?>

Comment: <?php $color='#ccc'; ?> color:<?=$color;?>

Comment: I need to use <?php the_field('main_color', 'option'); ?>

Comment: what is return this function??

Comment: It return this : #00A79D

Comment: so it's #00A79D Hex Color - RGB: 0, 167, 157 whats the problem this value must set!!!!